# what video streaming protocol does lybrate uses?

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, android-debug, openwebrtc

I would like to know, what streaming protocol does lybrate app uses...
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lybrate.phoenix&hl=en

OpenTOK, twilio or they have built their own API with underlying webRTC protocol?

Answer (score 0):

They are using the native library libopentok.so, so I suppose it corresponds to OpenTok.

Comment: Validate the answer then ;)